# velodyne(HDL-32E) something shadow occured why it happened?

Tags: ros-kinetic, velodyne

[image: Rosanswers logo]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HdJarMRYNJU

our velodyne use driver -> https://github.com/ros-drivers/velodyne

and i dont know why shadow occured what should i do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/286097/velodyne(hdl-32e)-something-shadow-occured-why-it-happened?/) by [dnjsxor564](https://answers.ros.org/users/34249/dnjsxor564/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2018-03-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevejp](https://answers.ros.org/users/33828/stevejp/) on 2018-03-21**:
It might be useful if you could post a bag file.

**Comment by [dnjsxor564](https://answers.ros.org/users/34249/dnjsxor564/) on 2018-03-21**:
oh thx but how to upload bag file?

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-03-22**:
Upload it to something like Google Drive or Dropbox, then post a link here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm using the same drivers and I experience the same phenomena with the HDL-32. However, if you save the point cloud, e.g. with...

```
$ rosrun pcl_ros pointcloud_to_pcd input:=/velodyne_points
```

...you should see that the full point cloud without the shadow. In addition, if you record the data and then play it back with `rosbag`, you shouldn't see the shadow but you may still see a "ripple" effect that rotates around the cloud in the same way.

I think that the problem is related to how RViz displays or refreshes point clouds in it's visual display. As far as I can tell it doesn't seem to adversely affect the point cloud in any way.

---

Originally posted by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) with karma: 2327 on 2018-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dnjsxor564](https://answers.ros.org/users/34249/dnjsxor564/) on 2018-03-21**:
i use bag file but i still can see shadow.. if u check my bagfile? and check shadow occured?
if u can help me i give my bagfile, please tell me your email thx.

**Comment by [M@t](https://answers.ros.org/users/26592/m@t/) on 2018-03-22**:
Hmmm... that's odd. It would be best if you could upload a sample bag file to something like Google Drive or Dropbox and then post a link to it in your question. Then everyone can see it and take a look.